# Kubernetes Alpha Debug command

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying the **debug** CLI feature on 1.18 release of Kubernetes but I have an issue while I have executed debug command.

I have created a pod show as below.

```
kubectl run ephemeral-demo --image=k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1 --restart=Never
```

After than when running this command: `kubectl alpha debug -it ephemeral-demo --image=busybox --target=ephemeral-demo`

Kubernetes is hanging like that :

```
Defaulting debug container name to debugger-aaaa.
```

How Can I resolve that issue?

Comment: output of kubectl version

Comment: `Defaulting debug container name to debugger-aaaa.` this is the only output of kubectl

Comment: Is your cluster also upgraded to Kubernetes 1.18?  My impression from the release notes is that this feature requires some server-side support.

Comment: Yes, I have setup a new cluster with version 1.18

Comment: Have you enabled [EphemeralContainers feature gate](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/#ephemeral-container-example)?

Comment: Yes this feature has been already enabled

Comment: I make the same observation. Does anybody know of an issue that covers this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need to enable the feature gate on all control plane components as well as on the kubelets. If the feature is enabled partially (for instance, only kube-apiserver and kube-scheduler), the resources will be created in the cluster, but no containers will be created, thus there will be nothing to attach to.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63504307/9521610) posted by [Konstl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5365251/konstl)

To enable `EphemeralContainers` featureGate correctly, add on the **master** nodes to:

```
/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml  
/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml  
/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml
```

the following line to container command:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-apiserver # or kube-controller-manager/kube-scheduler
    - --feature-gates=EphemeralContainers=true  # < -- add this line
```

Pods will restart immediately.

For enabling the featureGate for `kubelet` add on **all** nodes to:

```
/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml
```

the following lines at the bottom:

```
featureGates:
  EphemeralContainers: true
```

Save the file and run the following command:

```
$ systemctl restart kubelet
```

This was enough in my case to be able to use `kubectl alpha debug` as it's explained in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/#ephemeral-container)

Additional usefull pages:

- [Ephemeral Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/ephemeral-containers/)
- [Share Process Namespace between Containers in a Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/share-process-namespace/)

Comment: This is what I did as well (I simply edited my `kubeadm-config` and `kubelet-config-1.xx` ConfigMaps, then issued `kubeadm upgrade node` && `systemctl restart kubelet`). I did get the hang described by the author until I performed these steps on **each** node. It's because the kubelet in charge of pulling the ephemeral container isn't able to without the gate enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing similar behaviour. Although i'm running 1.17 k8s with 1.18 kubectl. But I was under the impression that the feature was added in 1.16 in k8s and in 1.18 in kubectl.